# Generate list of numbers and their negative counterparts in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a convenient one-liner to generate a list of numbers and their negative counterparts in Python?

For example, say I want to generate a list with the numbers 6 to 9 and -6 to -9.

My current approach is:

```py
l = [x for x in range(6,10)]
l += [-x for x in l]
```

A simple "one-liner" would be:

```py
l = [x for x in range(6,10)] + [y for y in range(-9, -5)]
```

However, generating two lists and then joining them together seems inconvenient.

Comment: Should the positive numbers come before the negative ones?

Comment: @Erich No, the order doesn't matter in my case.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, does it even need to be a list? Would a set be OK (which is unordered), or a generator or tuple (both of which are ordered)?

Comment: @J.G. I might want to create a figure later on. Supposedly using [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) etc. So any ```scalar or array-like, shape``` would be fine.

Comment: Beside the point, but `l` is a bad variable name since it looks like `1` and `I`. Use something like `L` instead. [per PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid)

Comment: Most of these answers are reading like some anti-golf solutions; sorting, generator functions, itertools. I would much rather maintain the code you provided than most of the 'answers'.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I am unsure if order matters, but you could create a tuple and unpack it in a list comprehension.

```
nums = [y for x in range(6,10) for y in (x,-x)]
print(nums)
[6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8, 9, -9]
```

Answer (score 65):

Create a nice and readable function:

```
def range_with_negatives(start, end):
    for x in range(start, end):
        yield x
        yield -x
```

Usage:

```
list(range_with_negatives(6, 10))
```

That is how you get a convenient one-liner for anything. Avoid trying to look like a magic pro hacker.

Comment: Prejudice against list/dict comprehensions is quite common on SO, and it's usually justified by saying that they're not "readable".  The inherent readability of a construct (rather than *how* it's used) is largely subjective.  Personally I find comprehensions *more* readable, and this solution much less so (Compare: "write down the blood pressure of every male over 50" vs. "Go through every person. OK, are they male? If so, then..."). I use them for this reason, not because I'm trying to "look like" anything.  Long comprehensions can be broken over multiple lines if that's the problem.

Comment: Fair enough. But that's where the subjectivity comes in: I personally *do* find the list comp solution at least as readable, in terms of mental strain, as the generator function. I would however improve readability (or rather, readability-for-me) of Datanovice's answer by renaming `y` to `signedValue`.   To me the real added value of the define-a-function approach would be to deliver results in the strict order the question asked for (positive, then negative) while avoiding the problem of Barmar's `chain` one-liner in which slightly-different numeric arguments have to be hard-coded in twice.

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment about list comprehensions, but defining a function like this is also a very useful technique to know. (It's especially powerful to collect results from a recursive algorithm by writing a recursive generator and passing the top-level result to `list` or whatever.) After years of trying to codify how best to make these decisions, the only general principle that makes sense to me: if there's an obvious, good name to give to something in the program, take the opportunity to do so (and functions are one of the ways we do this).

Answer (score 61):

I'd say the simplest solution is to unpack two ranges into a list using the `*` unpacking operator:

```py
>>> [*range(6, 10), *range(-9, -5)]
[6, 7, 8, 9, -9, -8, -7, -6]
```

Not only is this the shortest answer proposed yet, it's also the most performant, because it only constructs a single list and involves no function calls beyond the two `range`s.

I verified this by testing all of this question's answers using the `timeit` module:

| Answer ID | Method | timeit result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (in question) | `[x for x in range(6,10)] + [y for y in range(-9, -5)]` | 0.843 usec per loop |
| (this answer) | `[*range(6, 10), *range(-9, -5)]` | 0.509 usec per loop |
| 61348876 | `[y for x in range(6,10) for y in (x,-x)]` | 0.754 usec per loop |
| 61349149 | `list(range_with_negatives(6, 10))` | 0.795 usec per loop |
| 61348914 | `list(itertools.chain(range(6, 10), range(-9, -5)))` | 0.709 usec per loop |
| 61366995 | `[sign*x for sign, x in itertools.product((-1, 1), range(6, 10))]` | 0.899 usec per loop |
| 61371302 | `list(range(6, 10)) + list(range(-9, -5))` | 0.729 usec per loop |
| 61367180 | `list(range_with_negs(6, 10))` | 1.95 usec per loop |

<sup>(timeit testing performed with Python 3.6.9 on my own computer (average specs))</sup>

Comment: I'm not too keen on assuming performance is relevant when all you have is an example with <10 items, but this clearly is the simplest solution.

Comment: How do you figure out the start and end of the negative values without hardcoding them?

Comment: @aldokkani `[*range(x, y), *range(-y + 1, -x + 1)]`

Comment: @RoadrunnerWMC I'd suggest `[*range(x, y), *range(-x, -y, -1)]` for even better readability.

Comment: And I'd suggest putting that into the answer because right now it is too specific and "hard-coded"-y

Answer (score 25):

You can use `itertools.chain()` to concatenate the two ranges.

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain(range(6, 10), range(-9, -5)))
```

Comment: I would use ‘range(-6, -10, -1)’ for clarity of order doesn't matter ( and replace the 6 and 10 with variables)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `itertools.product`, which is the cartesian product.

```py
[sign*x for sign, x in product((-1, 1), range(6, 10))]
[-6, -7, -8, -9, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This might be slower because you use multiplication, but should be easy to read.

If you want a purely functional solution, you can also import `itertools.starmap` and `operator.mul`:

```py
from itertools import product, starmap
from operator import mul

list(starmap(mul, product((-1, 1), range(6, 10))))
```

However, this is less readable.

Comment: I find the use of `product`, `starmap`, and `opertaor.mul` unnecessarily obtuse compared to nested list comprehensions, but I approve of the suggestion of using multiplication. `[x * sign for sign in (1, -1) for x in range(6, 10)]` is only 10% slower than than `[y for x in range(6, 10) for y in (x, -x)]`, and in cases where order matters, more than 3x faster than sorting the tuple-based approach.

Comment: This is a neat idea, but perhaps a bit too specific to the problem details. The techniques offered by others apply more generally.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I agree that `starmap` and `mul` should be avoided, but I think `product` makes it more readable, as it groups the iterators and their elements separately. Double loops in list comprehension can also be confusing, due to their unexpected order.

Answer (score 10):

You're really close, with combining two `range` objects. But there is an easier way to do it:

```
>>> list(range(6, 10)) + list(range(-9, -5))
[6, 7, 8, 9, -9, -8, -7, -6]
```

That is, convert each `range` object to a list, and then concatenate the two lists.

Another approach, using itertools:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(range(6, 10), range(-9, -5)))
[6, 7, 8, 9, -9, -8, -7, -6]
```

`itertools.chain()` is like a generalized `+`: instead of adding two lists, it chains one iterator after another to make a "super-iterator". Then pass that to `list()` and you get a concrete list, with all the numbers you want in memory.

Comment: This answer is valuable simply for the insight that `[x for x in ...]` is better spelled `list(...)`.

Answer (score 7):

IMO the approach using `itertools.chain` presented in a couple of other answers is definitely the cleanest out of those provided so far.

However, since in your case [the order of the values doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348795/generate-list-of-numbers-and-their-negative-counterparts-in-python#comment108529386_61348795), you can avoid having to define two explicit `range` objects, and thus avoid doing all the off-by-one math necessary for negative `range` indexing, by using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((x, -x) for x in range(6, 10)))
[6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8, 9, -9]
```

Tad verbose, but readable enough.

Another similar option is to use tuple/argument unpacking with plain `chain`:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*((x, -x) for x in range(6, 10))))
[6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8, 9, -9]
```

More concise, but I find tuple unpacking harder to grok in a quick scan.

Answer (score 5):

Weighing in with yet another possibility.

If you want readability your original one-liner was pretty good, but I would change the ranges to be the same as I think the negative bounds make things less clear.

```
[x for x in range(6, 10)] + [-x for x in range(6, 10)]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a variation on a theme (see [@Derte Trdelnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4508178/derte-trdelnik)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61349149/7844823)) following the philosophy of [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) where

> iterator building blocks [...] are useful by themselves or in combination.

The idea is that, while we're defining a new function, we might as well make it generic:

```
def interleaved_negatives(it):
    for i in it:
        yield i
        yield -i
```

and apply it to a particular [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) iterator:

```
list(interleaved_negatives(range(6, 10)))
```

Answer (score 3):

**There can be different ways to get the job done.**

Variables given:
 1. start=6 
 2. stop=10

#### You can try this also, for different approach:

```
def mirror_numbers(start,stop):
  if start<stop:
    val=range(start,stop)
    return [j if i < len(val) else -j for i,j in enumerate([x for x in val]*2) ]

mirror_numbers(6,10)
```

Answer (score 3):

using itertools:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(range(6, 10), range(-9, -5)))
[6, 7, 8, 9, -9, -8, -7, -6]
```

`itertools.chain()` is like a generalized `+`: instead of adding two lists, it chains one iterator after another to make a "super-iterator". Then pass that to `list()` and you get a concrete list, with all the numbers you want in memory.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61371302/7259176) already exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the order you've specified, you can make use of Python's built-in range generator with a conditional:

```
def range_with_negs(start, stop):
    for value in range(-(stop-1), stop):      
        if (value <= -start) or (value >= start):
            yield value
```

Which gives you the output:

```
In [1]: list(range_with_negs(6, 10))
Out[1]: [-9, -8, -7, -6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And also works with 0 as the start for the full range.

Comment: This is very inefficient for large values of `start`.

Answer (score 2):

l just like symmetries.

```py
a = 6
b = 10

nums = [x+y for x in (-(a+b-1),0) for y in range(a,b)]
```

The result is `[-9, -8, -7, -6, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

I believe that the nums expression can be improved, what follows "in" and "range" still looks unbalanced to me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like only two answers really gave one-liners, so here's another one:

```
[i for l in map(lambda x: (x, -x), range(6, 10)) for i in l]
```

```
[6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8, 9, -9]
```

Comment: Why the unnecessary map/lambda?