# Create Python alternating range programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a convenient way to create an ordered, alternating (negative, positive while decrementing and incrementing by one from previous pair) list of integers in the form of

```
[-1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, 5, -6, 6, -7, 7, -8, 8, -9, 9, -10, 10]
```

with Python with variable length/end integer, like:
`alternating_range(2) = [-1, 1, -2, 2]`

I can easily do this in a "for loop" but I am looking for a more "Pythonic" way

Comment: A for-loop is not _pythonic_?

Comment: you can create a generator with a for loop inside.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution leveraging Python List Comprehensions / Generator Expressions or similar, following the "Flat is better than nested” Python approach

Comment: If you know how to do it with for loop you can convert that to list comprehension, if you consider it more pythonic.

Comment: @DaHoC The generator solution will be equally, or even more nested though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate list of numbers and their negative counterparts in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348795/generate-list-of-numbers-and-their-negative-counterparts-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as a generator like this:

```py
def alternating_range(x):
    return (i for j in range(1, x+1) for i in (-j,j))
```

However, I think the for loop solution is more readable. You cite "flat is better than nested". This solution has only one level of nesting while the one above has 2.

```py
def alternating_range(x):
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        yield -i
        yield i
```

Both of these return generators, you can use `list(alternating_range(x))` to convert to a list.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible solutions:

The first one using list comprehension:

```py
def alternating(i : int) -> List[int]:
    return [i * sign for i in range(1, i + 1) for sign in [1, -1]]
```

And the second one using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np
def alternating(i : int) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.c_[(r := np.arange(1, i)), -1 * r].reshape(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun, use tail recursive:

```
def alternating_range(i, n=-1, p=1, res=[]):
    return res if i+1 == p else alternating_range(i, n-1, p+1, res+[n,p])

print(alternating_range(10))

# [-1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, 5, -6, 6, -7, 7, -8, 8, -9, 9, -10, 10]
```

or while loop:

```
def alternating_range(i, n=-1, p=1, res=[]):
    while p <= i: res += [n, p]; n, p = n-1, p+1
    return res

print(alternating_range(10))

# [-1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, 5, -6, 6, -7, 7, -8, 8, -9, 9, -10, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something fancy, if however not very efficient, like this:

```
def alternating_range(end):
  return list(sum(map(lambda x: (x*-1, x), range(1, end+1)), ()))

print(alternating_range(10))
```

No imports required, no apparent nesting (for-loop) in your code

Answer (score 0):

Another (quite ugly looking) option, using list comprehension with only one for statement is:

```py
def alternating_range(n):
    return [
        (i + (i % 2) - int((i + 1) / 2)) * (-1)**i
        for i in range(1, 2 * n + 1)
    ]
```